# Problems opening a question link into an iframe

Tags: support, scripts

When we execute a search request we can get back a list of matching questions.  One of the properties of the response is called "link" which is a URL to the question itself.

In my application, I wished to open this URL within an HTML `<iframe>` within the page but it doesn't work.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

When an HTTP request to show a page is sent to the Stack Exchange web site, a check is explicitly made to ensure that returned page is **not** loaded into an `<iframe>`.  The response header that comes back for `X-Frame-Options` is `SAMEORIGIN` which means that only pages loaded from the same origin can be included in the `<iframe>`.  There are good reasons for restricting pages from being loaded within `<iframe>`s and Stack Exchange have deliberately chosen this policy.

The bottom line is don't try and load pages from Stack Exchange within your own `<iframe>`s, they won't work by design and intent.

To read more about the X-Frame-Options response, read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) and the technical spec in [RFC7034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7034).

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to open Stack Exchange sites in an iframe and doing so might violate the terms of service.
Also, attempting to do this is part of [a technique used by cyber-criminals ("clickjacking")](http://javascript.info/tutorial/clickjacking).  You don't want to look like one of them. ;)

If you try, your browser will give you errors like:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: `http://meta.stackexchange.com/{etc.}` does not permit cross-origin framing.

You can look up "iframe buster, busters" and try to beat the system, but **the *correct*/allowed way to mash up two or more web pages is to pull Stack Exchange data from [the *Stack Exchange API*](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).**